# How to checkout a single file from a future commit on the same branch?

Tags: git

I recently encountered failing test cases which started happening several commits ago, so to investigate I checked out the commit when they first started failing. This is the 'merge of master' commit shown below (by `gitg`; the branch is called `editable_phone_type`):

[image]

So now my `HEAD` is at that commit:

[image]

Among the files that differ is a migration that I'd like to check out:

```
(venv) Kurts-MacBook-Pro:lucy-web kurtpeek$ git diff --name-only HEAD editable_phone_type
lucy-web/dashboard/templates/families/index.html
lucy-web/dashboard/tests/test_families.py
lucy-web/lucy_web/migrations/0103_merge_20180216_1050.py
lucy-web/lucy_web/test_factories/family_factory.py
```

However, if I try `git checkout editable_phone_type -- <the migration file>`, I get a `pathspec` error:

```
(venv) Kurts-MacBook-Pro:lucy-web kurtpeek$ git checkout editable_phone_type -- lucy-web/lucy_web/migrations/0103_merge_20180216_1050.py
error: pathspec 'lucy-web/lucy_web/migrations/0103_merge_20180216_1050.py' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

What would be the right way to check out a file from a future commit on the same branch?

**Update**

Using `git diff --name-status` instead of `--name-only` indicates that the migration file has status of `A` (added):

```
(venv) Kurts-MacBook-Pro:lucy-web kurtpeek$ git diff --name-status HEAD editable_phone_type
M       lucy-web/dashboard/templates/families/index.html
M       lucy-web/dashboard/tests/test_families.py
A       lucy-web/lucy_web/migrations/0103_merge_20180216_1050.py
M       lucy-web/lucy_web/test_factories/family_factory.py
```

Does this mean that it is not possible to check it out?

**Update 2**

I just noticed that the path provided by `git diff --name-status` (or `--name-only`) includes the directory that I'm in, `lucy-web`. I had inadvertently copy-pasted the whole path. If I instead copy-paste starting from the subdirectory `lucy_web` it works:

```
(venv) Kurts-MacBook-Pro:lucy-web kurtpeek$ git checkout editable_phone_type -- lucy_web/migrations/0103_merge_20180216_1050.py
(venv) Kurts-MacBook-Pro:lucy-web kurtpeek$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git checkout editable_phone_type -- \
        lucy-web/lucy_web/migrations/0103_merge_20180216_1050.py
```

That's the right way to checkout content from a commit, give the commit and  the path.  I'm pretty sure you've got a typo in your pathname somewhere, case differences or hyphen-uscore mixup, or something.  That path really doesn't exist in that commit.

Try `git ls-tree -r editable_phone_type | grep -i merge.2018` or something to see what's up.

... ah. Give `--name-status` instead of `--name-only`, I'm thinking it wasn't so much a type as the file was just plain deleted.

Answer (score 2):

The checkout syntax you specified is correct, and it doesn't matter whether it's a future commit, a past commit, or a commit from a totally separate branch.  As long as you provide a "<tree-ish>" (an identifier that tells git what tree of content to look at) and a path that identifies a file in that "<tree-ish>", it should be fine.

So the most likely thing is that the path in question *dosen't* exist in the tree for the commit at the tip of the `editable_phone_type` branch.  While the error message may be misleading in this case (since it's hard to see how a file in the *current* commit is not "known to git"), it is nonetheless the error you would get in this case.

Your diff output seems to show that this is a file that exists either in your HEAD commit, or in the branch commit, or both (but with differing content).  So the most likely case is that it's present in `HEAD` but not on the branch.  You can confirm by changing your diff command, as

```
git diff --name-status HEAD editable_phone_type
```

If git prints a `D` at the start of the line where it names your file, this confirms that it doesn't exist in the `editable_phone_type` commit.

In that case, of course, you can "check out the `editable_phone_type` version" simply by removing the file from your work tree.